# Make answer class a struct?

Tags: c#, class, struct

Usually play around with making games but I'm taking a detour into making a little question and answer app, for educational purposes.

Anyway I have a question class which holds numerous members: the question itself, **the answer to the question**, an array of possible answers etc. No doubts this should be a class.

My answer class however only holds a string, an Enum and an int id number as shown below:

```
public class Answer
{
    public string Answer { get { return answer;} private set { answer = value; } } 
    public Answer_Category = Some_Value; // The enum.
    public int ID { get { return id; } private set { return id; } }

    private string answer;
    private int id;
}
```

Ok so it holds two strings, also the ctor has been out.

So should I be making this a struct? I ask as it seems comparable to making a Vector a struct, being such a small data structure 'n all.

Naturally being a question and answer application the answer class/struct is going to be the subject of a lot of search calls.

IMO this should be a struct - solely because of the size of the structure, haven't played around with C# for some time though so just looking for some clarification.

Comment: Personally I feel entities should always be a class unless there's a really god reason to make them structs (which I don't see here). I'll be interested to see the answers. You may want to add a little more about how the entity will be used in your code...

Comment: a good starting point for your decision would be the microsoft guidlines concerning structs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @fuchs777 I have trawled through what MS have to say on structs, and it's riddled with contradiction e.g. Vector2/Vector3 being structs in Xna, the Rectangle struct (again XNA).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decision boils down to whether you want a value type or a reference type. In other words what do you want the assignment operator to mean? If you want assignment to copy the value, use a struct. If you want assignment to take another reference e, use a class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Yeah I get the value vs. reference thing. Think I got too deep in an article stating it should be used when the object is immutable, small data type etc. Seeing as how this is a Q&A app there'll be a lot of loading questions and answers for comparison. Class is definitely the way for this type. Thanks again for sparking that :P

Answer (score 1):

There are two primary usages cases for structures: for situations where one wishes to conveniently move around aggregations of independent variables (such as the coordinates of a point), or where a small immutable object will often be used in situations where identity is not important (as would be the case with e.g. `Decimal` or `DateTime`).  Since a variable of structure type simply holds an aggregation of variables, structures which are used for that purpose should simply expose their contents as public fields.  Doing so will make clear that any invariants that might be applicable to structure members will be the responsibility of the code creating the structure.  For example, if one has a structure `MinMax` with `int` members `Minimum` and `Maximum`, using exposed public fields for those members would make clear that the structure itself makes no promise that `Maximum >= Minimum`.  A method which returns such a structure may promise that it will not return one where `Maximum < Minimum`, but methods which receive structures and want `Maximum >= Minimum` will have to check those fields themselves.  On the flip side, code which wishes to set those values in a structure will be able to set them in whatever order is convenient, without having to worry about the struct throwing an exception because the `Minimum` was set higher than `Maximum`.

The MSDN guidelines assume that the purpose of any struct is to behave like an object.  Since piecewise-mutable structures don't behave like objects, structures which will be used like objects shouldn't be piecewise mutable.  On the other hand, aggregations of variables can be useful in and of themselves; one should use a struct in cases where one wants an aggregation of variables, but should try to make it as obvious as possible that the struct is an aggregation of variables rather than an object.